# How to show selected options of checkbox in dropdownlist to textbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a drop down with checkbox for multiple selections of options. Now whenever i select any checkbox of drop down list then i want to show that option in text box next to drop down list. If i deselect that option then that option should also removed from text box.

I searched a lot but didn't get proper solution.

```
<td style="padding-top: 10px" colspan="3">
                                    <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="ddlproduct" runat="server" AddJQueryReference="true" UseSelectAllNode="false">
                                        <Style SelectBoxWidth="200" DropDownBoxBoxWidth="200" DropDownBoxBoxHeight="200" />
                                        <Texts SelectBoxCaption="--Select--" />
                                    </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
                                    <asp:ExtendedRequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_ddlproduct" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<b>Required</b>" ControlToValidate="ddlproduct" ForeColor="Red"></asp:ExtendedRequiredFieldValidator>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtselectedproducts" runat="server" Width="573px"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>



 private void fetchandfillprod()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = DBConf.db_fet("select columnname from tablename with(nolock)");
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ddlproduct.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        ddlproduct.DataTextField = "columnname";
        ddlproduct.DataValueField = "columnname";
        ddlproduct.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I have used DropDownCheckBoxes.dll for checkbox in dropdownlist.

Comment: Where is the code ?

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link..this is exactly what you are looking for..
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Multiple-Select-MultiSelect-DropDownList-with-CheckBoxes-in-ASPNet-using-jQuery.aspx..

instead of alert bind the check box selected item to the textbox.

Comment: Thanks for your @Harish... I have already read this article. I dont want this on button click. I want to show options in textbox as soon as i select it in dropdownlist.

Comment: you can use jquery in order to achieve this..so refer some jquery things to do.

Comment: or you can even go for some methods of dropdown like OnSelectedIndexChanged and in code behind file bind the selected checkbox..

Answer (score 0):

Use `SelcetedIndexChanged` event, found an example and here is modified code. Also this is going to postback full page, i recommend you to use `UpdatePanel` with this.

```
   protected void ddlproduct_SelcetedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtselectedproducts.Text ="";

        foreach (ListItem item in (sender as ListControl).Items)
        {
             if (item.Selected){
                 txtselectedproducts.Text += Item.Text;
                 }
        }
    }
```

if it not work out here is [original post](http://saplin.blogspot.in/2011/05/dropdowncheckboxes-using-control.html).